# Replacing a specific character with a html tag in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to style a specific word in a string by wrapping it in a `<strong></strong>` tag. The problem is that This word will change all the time, so I was thinking of getting them to wrap the particular word in brackets (in an input text field), and then replace the opening and closing brackets with the opening and closing strong tags.

Eg:

```
"Who said (romance) was dead?"
```

would become

```
"Who said <strong>romance</strong> was dead?"
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Regular expression.?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve]. Add your attempts.

Comment: I was thinking that, but I don't know much about regular expressions. An example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with capturing group regex

```js
console.log(
  "Who said (romance) was dead?".replace(/\(([^)]+)\)/g, '<strong>$1</strong>')
);
```

```
/\(([^)]+)\)/g
```

Above regex will match all the string in between `(` and `)` and repcace the captured group data surround with `<strong>` tag.

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/sS5wT6/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I ended up using: `var slideHeading = $(".slide-heading").text();
    $(".slide-heading").html(slideHeading.replace(/\(([^)]+)\)/g, '<strong>$1</strong>'));` which did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

if an answer without regex is acceptable to you then try :)

```
var str = "Who said (romance) was dead?";

var wordToBeStronged = "romance";

str = str.split( "(" + wordToBeStronged + ")" ).join( "<strong>" + wordToBeStronged + "</strong>" );

console.log( str );
```

Comment: `split` and `join` will be slower than RegEx.

Comment: @Tushar you are correct about performance http://jsperf.com/split-and-join-vs-regex-1000/2 , but its not too bad actually. In fact regex is slower with bigger strings http://jsperf.com/split-and-join-vs-regex-1000/3